# tcl : the simplest way to grab number from string?

Tags: string, split, tcl, extract

Hi let say i have couple of name : `orange12 , blue124 , red909`
, and i want to grab the index number , in this case : 12 , 124 and 909. Ussually , i can use 'string range first last' to extract the substring .And  to get the first and last i will use 'string len orange' and 'string len orange12'. Now I'm looking another way to do it.

As comparison , in python , i can do something like :

```
'orange12'.split('orange')[1]
'blue124'.split('blue')[1]
'red909'.split('red')[1]
```

How can i do something like that in tcl ? I tried the 'split' in tcl , but seems complicated and couldn't make it works. In tcl how can i split by a word (not character) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, `scan` is the most useful tool. It's often overlooked too:

```
scan "green012" {%[a-z]%d} word num
# $word is now “green”
# $num is now “12”
```

Comment: And I overlooked it. Yep... this is better than my regexp reply

Comment: this is cool. But i got more question : how if i need it that 'scan' to return the value of word or num without have to store it into the 'word' and 'num' variables. I nee it to be used as onliner function in my python script. for example i want to change the name from 'orange12' to 'newname12'. I expect to do something like : newname[scan "orange12" {%d} ] , so the output should be : newname12. Right now the 'scan' command will return the number of matches

Comment: @andio: try `set name newname[lindex [scan "orange12" {%[a-z]%d}] 1]`, or even better `set name [string map {orange newname} "orange12"]`.

Comment: @Peter: thanks ... all that scripts work great :-) .

Comment: @Donal: Thanks for the enlightment... from your script, i finally extract something like this : `newname[scan $name [scan $name {%[a-zA-Z]}]%d  ] ` . where i can do this without have to know the word 'orange' from 'orange12' . so the source name can be any random name in format like : ANYNAMEanynumber. For example , the name like 'mywonderfulworld2345612'. Thanks guyz for your help and all of those scripts.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what string format you expect.

If it is a known word (without digits), e.g. 'orange', followed by some digits, you may remove the word:

```
% string map {orange ""} orange12
12
% string map {blue ""} blue124
124
% string map {red ""} red909
909
```

If it is only known that it is a word followed by digits, you may try a regular expression.

```
% regexp {\d+} orange12 index
1
% puts $index
12
```

Anyway, note that the digits are still represented as a string. If it starts with a zero it will be interpreted as an octal, when converted to numeric format, which may lead to unexpected results.

One option is passing it through `scan`:

```
% regexp {\d+} orange012 index
1
% puts $index
012
% expr 1*$index
10
% set index [scan $index %d]
12
% expr 1*$index
12
```

Edit: used one of Peter's suggestions

Comment: Consider the `regexp` variants `regexp -inline {\d+} orange12` (gives the number as return value) or `regexp {\d+} orange12 index` (a little simpler).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show you the best ways to solve your problem in Tcl, but to answer the question you posed, here's the equivalent code in Tcl:

```
package require textutil

lindex [textutil::splitx orange12 orange] 1
lindex [textutil::splitx blue124 blue] 1
lindex [textutil::splitx red909 red] 1
```

The `textutil` package is a part of `Tcllib`, the Tcl companion library. The `splitx` command is an extending replacement for the core command `split`: `splitx` takes a regular expression instead of a character set to determine where to split the string argument.

Documentation: [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [textutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html) package

Comment: PS: in addition to the other methods, one could also use something like `string trimleft $s abdeglnoru` (where `s` contains the color-number string), but that's in fact rather silly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i finally find the best answer for my own question, i'd like to share here :

```
set name orange12345
[scan $name [scan $name {%[a-zA-Z]}]%d ] 
#12345
```

where i can do this without have to know the word 'orange' from 'orange12' . so the source name can be any random name in format like : **ANYNAMEanynumber**. For example , the name like '**mywonderfulworld2345612**'.

Comment: Note that several of the solutions above likewise don't need to know what the word is. If this solution is an attempt to get away from getting two values from the `scan` command, that can be accomplished a bit simpler with `scan $name {%*[a-zA-Z]%d}`, which returns only the numeric value, regardless of what the word is.